# Magento all products set to noindex

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

this is not so much a development question, rather something (hopefully) to set in the backend. I want to set all my products (all configurable ones) within magento 1.7.0.2 to the meta-tag "noindex,nofollow".

But doing that for 450 products one after another is quite heavy. Isn't there an easier way to set the default value differently or to use phpmyadmin therefore?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for my thing this process worked out well:

1: Go to System > General > Design > Robots 
And set all pages globally to noindex,nofollow
2. Then - in my scenario - if you want to have categories though listed, then do that to the panel "Own design" exactly like @pankijs mentioned:

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="setRobots"><value>INDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
</reference>
```

3. For setting individual products now to a different robots-tag, you can go to Product > Meta Information and edit stuff within the dropdown-box there.

Comment: Sorry for marking my own answer as the best one - but for my particular situation it was.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your templates local.xml file to

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="head">
       <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

for only configurable product use:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

this will add meta tag you need for all products.

Comment: thanks. I guessed there'll be something like this. But if I'd want to have 20 products set to "index, follow" within the dashboard - this won't work right? It'd be just all products set to noindex independently of what's set in dashboard. I'd need it a bit more editable.

Comment: you can allways loop through all products in install script and change values programmatically, or edit catalog_product_entity_* table

Comment: What would "edit catalog_product_entity_* table " exactly mean? Going to phpmyadmin and edit the setting of that meta-tag in a bulk-action and then go to the dashboard and edit my 20 products to another value? That'd be perfect

Comment: product attribute values are saved in entity tables, each type (varchar, int etc..) have their own table. basically you need to get what type is this attribute and you need to get this attribute ID, then you can change all values with simple update query in myPhpAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would give you more flexibility:

http://inchoo.net/magento/per-product-meta-robots-tag-control-in-magento/

Then you could just write a simple script/query to set all (or a subset) products to `NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW`.